# Cut mp3 file at "header missing" error

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I have some malformed MP3 files. Specifically, they get through the desired audio fine, but after that FFplay reports:

```
[mp3float @ 0x7fd7cb82a600] Header missing
[mp3float @ 0x7fd7cb82a600] overread, skip -5 enddists: -2 -2
```

And, correspondingly, FFmpeg reports:

```
[mp3 @ 0x7fe0c180a400] Audio packet of size 749 (starting with 0F757F48...) is invalid, writing it anyway.
```

After that, in all players I've tried (FFplay, Audacity, iTunes, VLC), the last few seconds of the track repeat. All but FFplay also get confused about the duration of the track.

How can I fix these files?

*In case it needs to be said:* It doesn't matter to me whether the result uses FFmpeg or not, or if it involves multiple passes with or without different tools, so long as it's scriptable. I have quite a few of these. I'm on macOS 10.14.4. `ffmpeg -version`:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Also, avconv 12.3 doesn't log any errors at all, but doesn't fix the problem either.

**EDIT:** On further reflection I think the simplest solution, since the error is always the last part of the file, is to determine precisely when the error occurs and just truncate the stream. So, alternate sub-question (not totally confident about SE etiquette for this kind of thing): how can I determine the timestamp of an error?

Comment: How were these files created? Can you provide a link to one?

Comment: @llogan A slightly-but-not-very old (up-to-date at the time) version of youtube-dl, and probably not, sorry.

Comment: Can you re-download the files with a recent youtube-dl and try again?

Comment: @llogan I've made significant changes to the metadata since downloading them, and it'd be a sizeable task to redo. I don't actually have a list of them all, either, only a hunch; I'm hoping for something I can apply in place as I come across broken files.

Comment: Can you verify that the changes you made did not cause the issue?

Comment: I can't check now, since I don't have the originals, but I distinctly remember noticing the issue before re-cataloguing the tracks, fighting it a bit, and giving up.

Comment: (@llogan, whoops)

Comment: Don't know what to recommend. Nothing you tried seemingly cannot properly decode the files. The files seem to be damaged. How or why I don't know.

Comment: @llogan see revised question

Answer (score 0):

Load a *damaged* mp3 file into **mp3DirectCut.exe** then simply save the file with a new filename.

The program will automatically fix various errors in the file while saving it. Not certain if it will fix your particular problem, but worth a try.

mp3DirectCut is a tool for editing MP3's directly:

**http://mpesch3.de**

All the mp3 frames get re-written to the new file, and re-indexed. Thus many faults get fixed, without needing to re-encode the file (it doesn't get converted to .wav but is processed entirely as a sequence of .mp3 frames).